# Is it theoretically possible to find a factoring algorithm that runs in polynomial time?

Tags: computational-complexity, computer-science, cryptography, np

Given that we don't know if P=NP, what's to stop someone from finding tomorrow an algorithm that makes prime factoring, or any other trap-door function reversing for that matter, computationally feasible?
Are we basing all of our cryptography on "well, it doesn't seem possible"?

Comment: this is an open problem, it seems unlikely, but no proof.

Comment: incidentally, this is the key selling point of quantum cryptography: the security is based on the laws of Nature (no-cloning theorem), rather than on algorithmic complexity arguments. (as with all "selling points", this is open to debate, see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04520)

Comment: 'Are we basing all of our cryptography on "well, it doesn't seem possible"?' TL;DR: yes

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is a research level question but since it is about an open problem I'll interpret it as such. At this point, we cannot prove that there is a polynomial time factoring algorithm. Strictly speaking, the conjecture that there is not one is stronger than $P \neq NP$ since factoring appears to not be an NP-complete problem. In fact, factoring is almost certainly weaker than NP-complete. In particular, almost as strongly as we believe that $P \neq NP$ we believe that $NP \neq coNP$. But factoring lives in the intersection of $NP$ and $coNP$ so if it were $NP$ complete then we'd end up with $NP =coNP$.

Minor note here: strictly speaking in order to make "factoring" a problem we want to talk about in this framework we need to make it a decision problem. "Factor $n$" isn't a yes or no problem. To make factoring a decision problem we instead phrase it as "Given $a$, $b$, and $n$ does $n$ have a prime factor between $a$ and $b$?" This is a decision problem and it isn't too hard to see that you can do this type of problem efficiently if and only if you can efficiently factor $n$.

It is also worth noting that we don't really have any strong reasons to believe that factoring is actually hard, other than that lots of people have tried to come up with a way to do it efficiently. There's no known broader structural collapse of complexity classes which occurs if factoring is in $P$.

Finally, note that not all cryptography depends on factoring being hard for security. Some specific protocols do, such as RSA, but we're in the process of transitioning away from such systems anyways, because there is [an efficient quantum algorithm to factor numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) In fact, many other cryptographic systems will also be vulnerable to quantum attacks- elliptic curve cryptography will be similarly vulnerable. The hope that there exists not just one-way functions but one-way functions which are hard for quantum computers  is a much much stronger claim than even $P \neq NP$ and while it is widely believed, my understanding is that don't have really great structural reasons for believing that either.